# What is the use of "android:hintAnimationEnabled" in TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

1.What is the use of  `android:hintAnimationEnabled` in `TextInputLayout`?

2.What is the difference between `android:hintAnimationEnabled` and `android:hintEnabled`?

Answer (score 4):

> 1.What is the use of android:hintAnimationEnabled in TextInputLayout?

When you click (focus) on an empty `EditText` with hint, the hint text animates and slides upwards. `android:hintAnimationEnabled` allows you to enable or disable this animation.

Check the image below:

[image: An example of android:hintAnimationEnabled]

> 2.What is the difference between android:hintAnimationEnabled and android:hintEnabled?

`android:hintEnabled` was added in [design library 23.2.0](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#setHintEnabled(boolean)).

`android:hintEnabled="true"` (Enabled) : Shows the hint floating on the top of `EditText` when focused or when having text set into the `EditText`

`android:hintEnabled="false"` (Disabled) :  Doesn't show the hint floating on top of `EditText`, it means, the hint is visible at the same place when empty `EditText` is focussed and vanishes off as soon as the first character is entered.

In short, `android:hintAnimationEnabled` enables/disables the hint animation while `android:hintEnabled` enables/disables the floating behaviour of hint.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this. It has a clear view of TextInputLayout hintAnimation 
https://www.journaldev.com/14748/android-textinputlayout-example

**UPDATE**

When you set a hint in TextInputLayout is shows as like as a normal textView Hint. But when user click on EditText the hint slide and goes little upwards.

[image]

And , if you disable hint animation, then it won't show any animation for hint text.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a hint ;)

Animation is a different property than the Hint text being there  at all

In other words, you can't animate something that's disabled. But you don't need animation to show the value

You're welcome to read what the difference is. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html